# Specify specific certificate when encrypting web.config connection string section

Tags: iis, encryption, web-config

Is there any possibility of encrypt sections in web.config with a specific certificate (not de default one), so I can read the same web.config in different machines?

Or... encrypt sections so two servers can decrypt automatically?

Both machines are Windows Server 2019

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

According to your descritpion, I suggest you could try to follow below steps to encrypt the web.config and decrypt the web.config by using certificate.

1.Create a certificate to encrypt the config file.

$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type DocumentEncryptionCert -Subject "CN=DevConfig" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec KeyExchange

```
Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath ".\DevConfig.cer"

$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "1234" -Force -AsPlainText

Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -FilePath ".\DevConfig.pfx" -Password $mypwd

$cert
```

2.Improt the encypt certificate:

```
Import-Certificate -Filepath ".\DevConfig.cer" -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

3.Imprort the decrypt certificate:

```
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "1234" -Force -AsPlainText

Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath ".\DevConfig.pfx" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password $mypwd
```

4.Install the WebConfigEncrypter NuGet package.

```
Install-Package WebConfigEncrypter -Version 1.1.0
```

5.Add below config into web.config file. Notice: you should find the thumbprint from the generated certificate file like below:

[image]

```
  <configProtectedData>
    <providers>
      <add name="Pkcs12Provider" thumbprint="91cb0b7c611e54f6bfd43c4d8d178b542bc6557e" type="WebConfigEncrypter.Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider, WebConfigEncrypter" storeLocation="LocalMachine"/>
    </providers>
  </configProtectedData>
```

6.Run below command in the web.config file fodler:

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "." -prov "Pkcs12Provider"
```

7.You will find your web.config is encrypted, but if you improt the decrypt certificatie in the remote server, you will find your application work well.